# Google Cloud Translate: num_valid_languages_in_csv = 1

Tags: python, translate, glossary

Attempting to add a glossary to Google Cloud Translate, but am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python_SetGlossary.py", line 36, in <module>
    result = operation.result(timeout=90)
  File "C:\Programming Installs\Python\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\future\polling.py", line 127, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.GoogleAPICallError: None Failed to parse content of input file. Error: Not enough valid languages in CSV file. Must have terms for at least two different languages. num_valid_languages_in_csv = 1
```

The CSV file (below) was created using the example [provided by Google](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#format-glossary) for equivalent terms sets.

```
en,fr,pos
Canadian Meteorological Service of Environment Canada,Service météorologique d'Environnement Canada,noun
Jacques Cartier Strait,détroit de Jacques-Cartier,noun
the St. Lawrence Global Observatory,l'Observatoire global du Saint-Laurent,noun
St. Lawrence Global Observatory,Observatoire global du Saint-Laurent,noun
```

This was uploaded to Google Cloud Storage. I then attempted to create an online glossary by making at available to the Cloud Translation API, again via the [code provided by Google](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#create-glossary) for equivalent terms sets.

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3 as translate

# def sample_create_glossary(project_id, input_uri, glossary_id):

"""Create Glossary"""
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

# TODO(developer): Uncomment and set the following variables
project_id = 'testtranslate'
glossary_id = 'glossary-en-fr-bidirectional'
input_uri = 'gs://bidirectional-en-fr/bidirectional-glossary.csv'
location = 'us-central1'  # The location of the glossary

name = client.glossary_path(
    project_id,
    location,
    glossary_id)
language_codes_set = translate.types.Glossary.LanguageCodesSet(
    language_codes=['en', 'fr'])

gcs_source = translate.types.GcsSource(
   input_uri=input_uri)

input_config = translate.types.GlossaryInputConfig(
    gcs_source=gcs_source)

glossary = translate.types.Glossary(
    name=name,
    language_codes_set=language_codes_set,
    input_config=input_config)

parent = client.location_path(project_id, location)

operation = client.create_glossary(parent=parent, glossary=glossary)

result = operation.result(timeout=90)
print('Created: {}'.format(result.name))
print('Input Uri: {}'.format(result.input_config.gcs_source.input_uri))
```

Can anybody help me figure out what is going on / what I'm doing wrong? (Or what Google is doing wrong. Some of their documentation is definitely suspect. But also I am not particularly experienced with Python and could easily be missing something.)

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, it required the first column in the CSV to be blank.

```
,en,fr,pos
,Canadian Meteorological Service of Environment Canada,Service météorologique d'Environnement Canada,noun
,Jacques Cartier Strait,détroit de Jacques-Cartier,noun
,the St. Lawrence Global Observatory,l'Observatoire global du Saint-Laurent,noun
,St. Lawrence Global Observatory,Observatoire global du Saint-Laurent,noun
```

No idea why, but it now works.

Comment: This is pretty weird but this worked out for me - adding first column blank and having pos and description column blank

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#tsv_and_csv

it's wrong: "Important: Do not include a header row"
you can add the language header to try out.

Answer (score 0):

There is two type of Glossary in Google Cloud Translate Advanced.

The first is [Unidirectional Glossaries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#unidirectional_glossaries)
This is just a simple a pair source language and target language in TSV, CSV or TMX format. Column header is not required.

Example data in CSV format

```
account,cuenta
directions,indicaciones
```

There is also the one you're currently using, they named it ["Equivalent term sets"](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#equivalent_term_sets_csv).
This format only available in CSV format. You use this format if you want to create a glossary with more than two languages. Header is required in this type of glossary.

Example data in CSV format :

```
first language,Second language,pos,description
account,cuenta,noun,A user's account. Do not use as verb.
```

Or, when there are 3 language :

```
first language,Second language,third language,pos,description
word in first language,word in second language, word in third language,noun,some information
```

As you can see, there are two extra column in this type of glossary: "**pos**" and "**description**". So at the minimum (when there is only a pair of language), there should be 4 column if you're using this type of glossary.

Also, in your case. You clearly need *Unidirectional* type of glossary instead of *Equivalent Term Sets*.

In your code above, instead of using `language_codes_set` you should use `language_pair`. You can see the [sample REST request here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#unidirectional_glossary) (It's lacking on Python sample code though).

Answer (score 0):

Adding info to Donovan's answer, it seems the correct way to create an Undirectional Glossary in python is:

1. define a LanguageCodePair

```
language_codes_pair = translate.Glossary.LanguageCodePair()
```

2. set source and target language attributes

```
language_codes_pair.source_language_code = 'source-language-code'
language_codes_pair.target_language_code = 'target-language-code'
```

3. create the glossary

```
glossary = translate.Glossary(name=name, language_pair=language_codes_pair, input_config=input_config)
```

This worked for me